# Spring MVC - send model to view and back to controller

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc

I have a problem with data flow in my app..

In the controller I am taking some model from DB, then I pass it to view - here some fields are shown (not all of them), and the user is able to modify them..
Then when he submits form, the controller should update the model in db.

The problem is flow, because not all of the fields are in  tags, so they won't pass after submiting the form.. 
The only solution I found, is to create additional  tags with all of the fields, which are not used in  to pass them forward..

But in case I have many fields, for example - 30, I would have to create a lot of hidden fields...

What solution do you think would be the best?

Greetings,
M.

Comment: retrieve the object before binding (use a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method for that). Put the model object in the session using `@SessionAttributes`.

Comment: retrieve model from db -> pass required values to view including model_id -> retrieve form submit data -> retrieve the same model from db again -> modify model with form values -> update in db  this way you avoid adding data to session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

1. Create a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method to get the model object from the database for each request
2. Put it in the session using `@SessionAttributes`.

### `@ModelAttribute` annotated method

Instead of having a GET method filling the model you can also use a [`@ModelAttribute` annotated method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods). This method will be invoked before each request handling method in the controller. One thing to take care of is that the id is passed in each request.

```
@ModelAttribute
public YourObject modelObject(@RequestParam long id) {
    return yourObjectDao.findOne(id);
}
```

Now you can simply remove the filling of the model from the GET method and add a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method argument to your POST method. Which will then use the freshly obtain object.

Drawback of this approach is that when using optimistic locking it doesn't work so well anymore because each time you get the most recent version.

### Using `@SessionAttributes`

Annotate your controller with [`@SessionAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-sessionattrib) this instructs the web handling to store the matching model objects in the session and retrieve them from there before binding.

```
@SessionAttributes("yourObject")
@Controller
public class YourController { ... }
```

Now in your POST method add an argument of the type `SessionStatus` and when everything is well call the `isComplete` method on that object. This will cleanup any session attributes put in the session by this controller.

```
public String handlePost(@ModelAttribute YourObject model, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    if (result.hasErrors) {
         return "yourView";
    } else {
         status.isComplete();
         yourObjectDao.save(model);
         return "redirect:your-new-view";
    }
}
```